# Problem when pass data in ReactJS with props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the problem when I try to pass the props through the function component .In parent component I have a state of currentRow with return an array with object inside, and I pass it to child component. It return a new object with an array inside it. What can I do to avoid it and receive exact my currentRow array.

there is example of the way I do it
Parent component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ToolBar from "./Toolbar";
function Manage() {
    const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState();
    console.log("from manage", currentRow);
    return (
        <div>
            <ToolBar currentRow={currentRow} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Manage;
```

Child Componet

```js
import React from 'react'
function ToolBar(currentRow) {
    console.log("from toolbar", currentRow);
    return(
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default ToolBar
```

And this is my Log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax5Gu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `React` component's props is always an object. The reason for this is that otherwise it would be impossible to access the properties of a component which received multiple props.

example:

```
<SomeComponent prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />

---

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  console.log(props.prop1);
  console.log(props.prop2);
}
```

So in order to resolve your issue, you could destructure the `props` object in your `ToolBar` component like this:

```
const ToolBar = ({ currentRows }) => {
  ...
}
```

Just keep in mind that a component will always receive its props as an object. There is no way to change that as of right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing it like below:

```
    import React from 'react'

    function ToolBar({currentRow}) {
        console.log("from toolbar", currentRow);
        return(
           <div></div>
        );
    }

    export default ToolBar
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, now it work correctly

Comment: Your most welcome